# unable to Install Ubuntu Desktop 13.10

Tags: installation, 13.10

Good day,

I am trying to perform a new install of Ubuntu-Desktop (ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso) using a USB. The machine boots into the USB however it starts alternating between a blank screen and a purple screen with the mouse cursor in the middle of the screen and eventually gives me the message/error below. When I hold down the shift key while its booting into the USB stick I get the menu with the options Try Ubuntu without installing, Install Ubuntu, Check disc for defects, Test Memory, Boot from first Hard disk. The only two options that perform the function it should are Check disc for defects and Test Memory. All other options alternate between a blank screen and purple screen and eventually the below message/error.

I have read many pages on the below message/error but all seem to be related to a machine that is either been upgraded from another version with the OS on the HDD therefore enabling them to perform many of the given fixes. I don't have any OS on the system and am trying to install for the first time. This machine used to have Windows XP but that no longer works missing system files therefore I am trying to install ubuntu 13.10. I have also tried installing using a DVD and that does the same.

I have downloaded a new copy of Ubuntu tested the checksum, tested the disk integrity all 100%. In the install menu I receive after pressing shift, I select nomodeset and have also tried to enter in the bottom line of text vga=771 but still nothing same as before.

**MESSAGE/ERROR:** The system is running in low-graphics mode Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.
After clicking OK I receive another menu but any option I choose there I get a grey screen and then nothing.

I am installing on a Desktop PC System: Mecer Xtreme Pentium 4 3015MHz, 500MB DDR RAM

Remember I have no working OS on the machine therefore I am not sure what to do, please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert, and my answer should really be in the comment area but I can't post there since I'm a guest. I would suggest trying the server iso as it uses a text based installer it should avoid any graphics issues, you can install the standard desktop experience to it once you have it up and running.

2 Things to keep in mind when installing the server edition for desktop use are. 1 when the option to install packages come up during the installation use the down arrow to go to "Manual Package Selection" DO NOT SELECT THE OPTION THOUGH, just press return to continue with your installation, 2 when you have successfully installed the OS and boot it up you will just see a terminal screen, you will need to enter your "username" then "password", then type "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" which will install your normal desktop interface found on the desktop version of ubuntu, alternatively if need be you can install a different desktop environment that is less demanding if needed such as "xubuntu-desktop".

I do not know that this will help solve your issue, but it's where I would start.